# R, plot.new has not been called from attempting to add text to a plot

Tags: r

I started to learn R code 3 days ago and have finally hit a point where I am stuck. When running the script an error message comes up.

```
Error in text.default(x = (x - 2 * sigma), y = 0.1, label = "Z =", z) : 
plot.new has not been called yet
```

I have tried placing it different lines of the codes, even in the ggplot command, same issue every time and I have absolutely no clue how to fix it, everything else works fine, I have included the full code below, with the text command being at the bottom, any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

```
library(cowplot)
print("This is a normal distribution for a sample mean for upper tail test")

x <- 130  # mean
sigma <- 30  #standard deviation
x_bar <- 150   #new mean for the hypothesis
n <- 2  #number of trials
z <- (x_bar - x) / (sigma / sqrt(n))
sig_level <- 0.05  #put at %/100 e.g. 50%/100 = 0.5

p1 <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(x - sigma*3, x + sigma*3)), aes(x))
p1 <- p1 +  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 101, args = list(mean = x, sd = 
sigma)) + ylab("")
p1 <- p1 +  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = range(x + sigma*3, x - sigma*3), color = 
'red3', size = 0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = range(x + sigma, x - sigma), color = 'blue3', 
size = 0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = range(x + sigma*2, x - sigma*2), color = 
'green', size = 0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = x, color='black', size = 0.5)


if (x_bar != -123456789) {
  p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = x_bar, color = 'darkmagenta', size = 1)
}

df <- data.frame(x, sigma, x_bar, n, z)
df
cat("the probability that the new mean =", x_bar,"is", 1-pnorm(z))

if (sig_level > 1-pnorm(z) | sig_level > pnorm(z)) {
  cat("Your new mean is in the critical region (", sig_level,") and is therefore unlikely")
}

text( x = (x - 2 * sigma), y = 0.1, label = "Z =", z)

plot(p1)
```

Comment: Use `p1 <- p1 + geom_text( aes(x=(x - 2*sigma), y=0.1, label=paste0("Z =", z)))` instead of `text( x = (x - 2 * sigma), y = 0.1, label = "Z =", z)`.

Comment: The above comment is another method to do the same !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **text()** function is used with the base plot function in R. That's why this error is coming.

As per you code : You are using ggplot plotting function. So you can use the **annotate()** function to achieve the same thing.

```
p1 + annotate("text", x=(x - 2 * sigma), y= 0.1, label=paste("z = ",z))
```

The running code is :

```
x <- 130  # mean
sigma <- 30  #standard deviation
x_bar <- 150   #new mean for the hypothesis
n <- 2  #number of trials
z <- (x_bar - x) / (sigma / sqrt(n))
sig_level <- 0.05  #put at %/100 e.g. 50%/100 = 0.5

p1 <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(x - sigma*3, x + sigma*3)), aes(x))
p1 <- p1 +  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 101, args = list(mean = x, sd = 
sigma)) + ylab("")
p1 <- p1 +  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = range(x + sigma*3, x - sigma*3), color = 
'red3', size = 0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = range(x + sigma, x - sigma), color = 'blue3', 
size = 0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = range(x + sigma*2, x - sigma*2), color = 
'green', size = 0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = x, color='black', size = 0.5)


if (x_bar != -123456789) {
  p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept = x_bar, color = 'darkmagenta', size = 1)
}

df <- data.frame(x, sigma, x_bar, n, z)
df
cat("the probability that the new mean =", x_bar,"is", 1-pnorm(z))

if (sig_level > 1-pnorm(z) | sig_level > pnorm(z)) {
  cat("Your new mean is in the critical region (", sig_level,") and is therefore unlikely")
}

p1 + annotate("text", x=(x - 2 * sigma), y= 0.1, label=paste("z = ",z))
```

Hope this could help you !